# What is the relationship between WiFi strength , the bandwidth, and the Internet speed?

Tags: networking, wireless-router, bandwidth

My school has a very low WiFi strength, -70dBm, but I have no problem downloading or streaming (the Internet speed test is 22/15 Mbps).  At home, the WiFi strength fluctuate a lot; when it's above -50 dBm, it has no problem at all, but when it's below -60dBm, the speed is barely functional. (I am using the free app WiFi Analyzer on my Android phone to measure the wifi strength.)

I am trying to fix my wifi problem at home but don't know if the problem is whether the ISP is not delivering the promised bandwidth, 175MB, or if the problem is that our router does not provide enough WiFi strength to reach my home, which is in a different room.

specs: ISP: Bell; router: bell1000.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the info. I believe changing the channel is the first thing I did. I am out so can't provide the exact specs, but I believe the modem has the option to automatically change channel.  But since there are only 14 channels (802.11n) and literally more than a hundred apartment, crowded channel could well be the root of problems.

Answer (score 0):

**Wi-Fi is for convenience, not for speed.** Also, replace anything Ethernet with Wi-Fi in the visual aids. Satellite TV has interference when it rains, the same thing can happen with Wi-Fi, when channels are over-crowded. In the Wi-Fi Analyzer app, it should tell you what the best channels are.

[image: forced description :/]

You should be able to switch channels in your router's configuration.
On Windows, go to the Start Screen, or Start Menu, and search for "cmd" once it opens, type "ipconfig" the "Default Gateway" for Wi-Fi should be there.

[image: VISUAL AID!]

On Mac, open System Preferences, and go into Network. CUE VISUAL AID!

[image: VISUAL. AID.]

You should go into a browser, then go to the default gateway, you should get the router's configuration page. Now, I don't have a Bell1000 router, but there should be a "Wireless" section in the Settings, on the sidebar (if there is one.)

[image: ANOTHER VISUAL AID, GOD YOU HAVE A SLOW CONNECTION!]

There should be a way to change the channel buried in there. Maybe a "save" button, keep in mind it may restart your router or Wi-Fi.

Oh, and it should look like this, I think there should be a channel thing, maybe in the other tabs.

[image: STOP ASKING ME TO PUT IN IMAGE DESCRIPTIONS!]

Comment: I would also suggest trying an "Auto" channel option, if there is one.  Many routers are pretty good at picking the cleanest channel on their own.  If you were to pick your own channel, I would say to steer clear of channels 1, 6, and 11 in the 2.4GHz range as they tend to be very crowded these days.

Answer (score 0):

Please veiw this video as this goes more indepth than I can explain at this time but if i find more information I will be sure to add it

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iZk0ksn0Yak
note: Optimizing your Wi-Fi Network as Fast As Possible
    - finding an appropriate location for your router/modem combo and or router

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AHbrVad86xw
note: Electromagnetic Interference as Fast As Possible
    - explains how Interference can affect signal on a Wi-Fi connection and or any connection

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hM8gZzSDKrw
note: Tri Band WiFi as Fast As Possible
    - A follow up on the 5Ghz band mentioned in Optimizing your Wi-Fi Network as Fast As Possible

and a little bit more on the 5Ghz and 2.4Ghz band is that between the two is that the speed for the data transfer on the 5Ghz band is much faster if the devices support it at higher speeds and there is available bandwidth, the distance for the 5Ghz is much smaller to a degree than the 2.4Ghz band yet it for this allows interference mentioned in the videos Optimizing your Wi-Fi Network as Fast As Possible and Electromagnetic Interference as Fast As Possible

Answer (score -1):

Within the normal range, the strength of the signal is not a problem as long as there is not another signal stronger on the same channel.

There are Windows / Linux applications that can show a diagram of the way the channels of multiple signals superimpose.

You have to check that and if that's the case, change your router  to a less overcrowded channel.